# Where does Nautilus store bookmark names?

Tags: gnome, nautilus, bookmarks

If I create a bookmark with Nautilus, its location is stored on `~/.gtk-bookmarks`, but not its name.

I've created a test bookmark named *weirdy*, and tried to do a `grep` on my home for that name, and I found nothing.

Where does Nautilus store bookmark names?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

They are stored in the `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` file

In older versions of Ubuntu they are stored in the `~/.gtk-bookmarks` file.

The format is:

```
file:///path/to/folder Bookmark_name
```

You can also specify other location protocols such as SFTP, FTP, or SMB:

```
sftp://username@hostname/path/to/folder Bookmark_name
```

Comment: Nautilus from Ubuntu 12.04 is not storing the names in there. However, that will work for storing new bookmarks, just what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Note: some characters are urlencoded in the location name (`#`, space, `¤`, `×`, etc.) some are not (`+`, `:`, `!`, `(`, `)`, etc.). It's not a good idea to use these in path names, but the distinction is quite curious.

Comment: Works for me in 14.04.

Comment: The path is same: `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` as Frantique stated, in Ubuntu 18.04 as well.

Answer (score 0):

A GUI method is to open a document from an application such as LibreOffice. Do a Save As and when the window opens, drag the folder into the left column.

I haven't a clue as to why the Preference gear was removed from Nautilus, but it should be restored IMHO.