# Remove favorites from nautilus

Tags: nautilus, language-support

Right after installing Ubuntu 16.04, I decided to [change the OS's language](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133318/how-do-i-change-the-language-via-a-terminal) from German to English. 
After rebooting, Ubuntu asked me if I would like to rename the personal folders and I agreed.

**Problem:** The new named favourite folders are not in the right section and the old ones still exist. I am not able to remove the old favourite folders by right clicking on then.

How can I restore the 'old' state but keep the new language?

[image]

Comment: In nautilus, there should be a "Bookmarks" or "Favorites" menu, there you can edit them.

Comment: unfortunately I could remove all the 'correct' favorite folders but not the 'dead' ones. Is there any other possibility ?

Comment: Have a look at the file `~/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. (This is based on [this answer to another question](http://askubuntu.com/a/484977/301745).) [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/192752/301745) might be relevant too.

Comment: @wjandrea Inside that config file there are the 'new' Favorites saved - so the english ones. No german folder names are in that file. Unfortunately when I click in nautilus on Desktop, for example, it requests for the german named desktop ... Where could I look for the still existing german folder names?

Comment: Maybe check `~/.config/user-dirs.locale`? I found that file by running `find ~ -name "*user-dirs*"`; there might be more like it.

Comment: what does your user-dirs.locale contain? mine does only "en_US"

Comment: Ah, OK. Mine is just "en_CA" for Canada

Comment: Have you tried to reboot again after you renamed the folders?

Comment: Could you open the file `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` and post the contents in your question?

Comment: After changing the config files do `nautilus -q` and open it again via unity to apply changes.