# Adapta theme nautilus menu in wrong language

Tags: nautilus, themes, directory, language-support

I recently installed Adapta theme and now I have a problem in Nautilus. The problem is that the folder shortcuts in nautilus is based on the wrong language, telling me "Folder not found" when I press.

The default language is set to English however the installation was made in Swedish, however, the standard procedure for changing the language of the folders seems to work as in the picture shows the default folders in the middle.

[image]

As you see the menu to the left are directed to folders that don't exists, since they point at `/home/uname/Dokument/` instead of `/home/uname/Documents/` etc... (Where *Dokument* is Swedish for *Documents*)

Is there a way to change these paths back to English so that the shortcuts work again?

**Edit**: I found a duplicate question here: [Remove favorites from nautilus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787450/remove-favorites-from-nautilus)

Comment: did you try reinstalling nautilus?

Comment: I already tired `sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus .... perhaps purge then install to clear config file

Comment: Ya, try purging and reinstall nautilus. Might've help

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a solution:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus-data

followed by

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus

thanks to ravery comments.

I also had to edit `~/.config/user_dirs.locale` to only contain "en_US" as well as double checking the `~/.config/user_dirs.dirs`

To apply the changes I had to do `nautilus -q` to kill the nautilus process and then open it again via unity, nothing else applied the changes.